# How to fasten up data transfer between two servers residing in different contents

Tags: wcf, http, tcp, binding, protocols

We are using basichttpbindings with WCF to transfer data to local servers and ones we own in different contents like South America, Australia etc.. from UK.

Now basichttpbinding with https is secure but way too slow. Someone suggested using TCP binding instead of http but network admin don't know what to do to make it secure.

Is there any definite solution to this scenario ?

Comment: You can use NetTcpBinding with SSL certificate. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-transport-security-and-message-credentials